# Stack Overflow Error When Converting Types with `From` Trait

Tags: rust, stack-overflow, fatal-error

I don't know how to express the issue generally in the title but I have encountered a stack overflow error while defining an Error struct to handle third party library errors. Here is an example code snippet.

```rust
pub struct Error(ErrorKind);

impl From<FooError> for Error {
    fn from(e: FooError) -> Self {
        e.into()
    }
}

impl From<BarError> for Error {
    fn from(e: BarError) -> Self {
        e.into()
    }
}

pub enum ErrorKind {
    Foo(FooError),
    Bar(BarError),
    Baz,
}

impl From<FooError> for ErrorKind {
    fn from(e: FooError) -> Self {
        Self::Foo(e)
    }
}

impl From<BarError> for ErrorKind {
    fn from(e: BarError) -> Self {
        Self::Bar(e)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct FooError;
pub struct BarError;


fn main() {
    let foo_e = FooError;
    dbg!(&foo_e);
    let _e = Error::from(foo_e);
}
```

When I wrote the `From<T>` implementation for `Error` type converting from a custom type e.g `FooError` unintentionally, I got surprised how the compiler understood the type conversion from `FooError` to `ErrorKind` then `Error` with a single expression `e.into()`. Then I moved on until I encountered a fatal error. Dived in what was the cause was and this was it. When I change the implementation to;

```rust
impl From<FooError> for Error {
    fn from(e: FooError) -> Self {
        Self(e.into())
    }
}
```

The error was gone. I don't think this is intentional where compiler is missing this. If this is a bug, I would like to contribute this to the language. If not what is the casue of the error and why is this allowed by the compiler.

Any professionals help would be appreciated.

Here is the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f2fe01f92fba128fd9983fa9b4b1988). Try it to reproduce the error.

Comment: Is there a question here, or is this an observation you wanted to share?

Comment: If this is a bug I would like to share and contribute if not I want to understand what is going on under the hood and why compiler allows without warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my misunderstanding. I know that the implenetation `impl From<A> for B` generates `Into<B>`. Due to this, `e.into()` inside the implementation is simply calling the `from` function recursively and that causes a stack overflow error.